# Pear error: Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 80 Deprecated

Tags: php, xampp, pear

I'm trying to install Media frontpage (www.mediafrontpage.net) to monitor my sickbeard/sabnzbd etc. I can't get it to work because of these annoying PEAR errors:

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 80 
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 166
```

The weird thing is, MediaFrontpage does not use pear at all! Still i get this annoying error.

I need PEAR for another application, so I can't just remove it.

See this screenshot, where you can see the errors: http://piclair.com/data/kfw8s.jpg

I have tried to upgrade pear using 'php go-pear.phar' on the commandline, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines responsible for the error would look something like

```
 $var = &new Something;
```

Remove the ampersand before `new`.

Comment: Hmm, and where would I find that piece of code then? I've searched in every page of mediafrontpage, and I can't find '&new' anywhere..

Comment: @Forza: `in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 80 ` would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Either set your error_reporting to anything without E_DEPRECATED (e.g. E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED or just to 0) or use a CMS that isn't based on old PHP versions.

Using this:

```
$object = &new class();
```

was a needed way to store objects as references in your code in earlier PHP versions, but in current versions all objects are references automatically, so using & before new is deprecated now

Answer (score 0):

it is simply pear package error which describes the problem about the assignment. so we can normally replace the assignment of
   **=& with =**
in the both line of the error statement.that will solve our problem.